# Operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'double' and 'decimal'

Tags: c#, console-application

I'm experiencing a problem when trying to run this program in VS. Any help? The error i get is:

> Operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'double' and 'decimal'

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter your height (in metres).");
            double height = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine("Please enter your weight (in kilograms).");
            double weight = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

            double kv_height = height * height;

            double bmi = weight / kv_height;

            Console.WriteLine("Your BMI is: " + bmi);
            if(bmi < 18.5)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("(Underweight)");
            }
            ***if(18.5 < bmi < 24.9)***
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

`if (18.5 < bmi < 24.9)` is causing the error. I am new to C#, so please excuse any messy code.

Comment: Is that really the error? not `Operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'double'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<` operator is a **binary operator** in C#. This means it works with two operands - left hand side operand and right hand side operand. What happened in your case is the evaluation from the left and began by comparing:

```
18.5 < bmi
```

This yields a `bool` result - either `true` or `false`. Essentially this result then can be put in place of the expression:

```
true/false < 24.9
```

Basically the code then tries to use `<` operator on `bool` and `double` data types. This can't be compared in C#, as `bool` has no implicit conversion to a number.

To fix this, you need to use another binary operator - `&&` and do two separate comparisons:

```
18.5 < bmi && bmi < 24.9
```

If both conditions are `true`, the whole expression is `true`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation and your help. Issue resolved.

Comment: Glad it helped, happy coding :-) !

Answer (score 1):

```
if(18.5 < bmi && bmi < 24.9)
```

In math we use 18.5 < bmi < 24.9 . In code is not like in math. '<' is a binary operator and it evaluates just 2 values and it gives a boolean value (true or false). If you have multiple conditions in if statement with same variable you must split the math condition (in your case) in subconditions like 18.5 < bmi && bmi < 24.9. This is the rule for the if statement.

Comment: Maybe you should explain why it gets rid of the problem. 1.0<a<2.0 being interpreted as (1.0<a)<b  is bool < double Hence the error

Comment: You were applying the < operand  on the result of the first condition  "18.5 < bmi" which is a boolean result

Comment: Consider improving your answer. _[Code-only answers may fall under 'Very Low Quality' ...and are candidates for deletion....We've always touted that we aren't a code factory. We are the people who teach others to fish. Code-only answers only feed a person for a day](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148272/is-there-any-benefit-to-allowing-code-only-answers-while-blocking-code-only-ques)_